# How to get maximum performance from a JavaEE server on a multi processor machine?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, multiprocessing, multicore

I have a server with 8 processors, 16 threads (Intel Xeon E5 E5-2630v3) and 64GB of RAM. I want to get maximum performance from my server.
I want to write a upload server on Java which will accept video files, stores in the remote storage and puts job in a queue to processing video files. But problem is that I don't know how JavaEE uses processors. If I run a java server will it use 8 processors or just 1?
I need to balance workload among all processors. Something like this:
*If I have 10 uploads at the same time then each processor will have 1 or 2 saving tasks.

If I have 100 uploads at the same time then each processor will have 12 or 13 saving tasks.*
How to correctly run JavaEE instances on tomcat to get maximum performance of a multi processor server? Is it better to run one instance of JEE project on tomcat or run 16 virtual machines with JEE instance on each?

Comment: A single instance is just fine :) Java is modern enough to know how to use multiple cores.

Comment: One JavaEE will do. But if this is critical, ensure having a maybe cheaper staging server, less well provided, say less processors. And then do load tests and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Operating System should take care of scheduling the jobs across all available processors and threads. Tomcat or any other server need not be configured to use more than one processor.
Although, the code running on the server may be implemented using newest java APIs specifically designed to utilize multi-core system.
Some references (not tested)
https://dzone.com/articles/building-multi-core-ready-java
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/03/20/java_8_security_multi_core/